# How to embed only most frequent words

Tags: python, word2vec

I want to implement a word2vec embedding for 100 (or X) most word used.

Here I encode the text to integers:

```
vocab_size = 100

data = nltk.sent_tokenize(train_text)

tokenizer = Tokenizer()
tokenizer.num_words = vocab_size
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(data)
tokenizer.oov_token = "UNK"

encoded = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(data)
```

One problem is that the above code just keeps the most frequent used words of each sentence in the encoded vector and discards the rest:

```
[1, 1, 5, 2, 15, 10, 5, 6, 28, 7, 13]
['s s in the that is in to be a with']
```

While the complete sentence is:

```
<s>although destroyed in 1910 , the 1771 mansion that is depicted in old photographs appears to be a georgian-style brick dwelling with gambrel-roofed brick wings .</s>
```

I would like to use a "UNK" for the words that are out of the most frequent words and a corresponding integer number in the encoded vector.

My main problem is for embedding part:

```
embedding_matrix = np.zeros((vocab_size, 50))
for word, i in tokenizer.word_index.items():
    embedding_vector = embeddings_index.get(word)
    if embedding_vector is not None:
        embedding_matrix[i] = embedding_vector
```

Here I just want to use the encoded integers not the index of each word so that I can keep the vocab_size the same as `100`

Could you please guide me on one or two of problems above?

Comment: Do you want to train a word2vec model on your own data, or trim some existing set of word-vectors down to the top-100 terms? If training your own model, are you using an existing library, or trying to implement the word2vec algorithm yourself? Is there a reason you want to replace all other words with `UNK`? (That's not typical and will probably make the word-vectors for the 100 remaining words worse, and the `UNK` vector also meaningless. It's more common in word2vec to simply ignore less-frequent/uninteresting words.)

Comment: @gojomo right, I think that's meaningless. About the embedding matrix I can limit the loop to the first 100 cases